# refresh the entire form inside onSubmit of AjaxButton in wicket framework

Tags: java, user-interface, wicket

I want to refresh the entire form on onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) of an AjaxButton.
How could this be done any comments.

Answer (score 7):

In the form constructor, or just before to add the form, set the form to output the markup id:

```
form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

And then on the `onSubmit` add your form to the `target`.

```
target.add(form);
```